# How can i configure azure blob storage with domain level privacy

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I'm using azure blob storage for videos. And i will embed these videos content on my website.
But i don't want these videos to be embed by anyone on any other website.
I don't know how to do that i research a lot of things but not getting the right way. I am talking about domain level privacy same as Vimeo is offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the 
**Cross-Origin Resource Sharing** (CORS) option. Further reading:
[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Support for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services)

Comment: I tried this but video are still running out of the domain.